# How do I add classes to main menu ul and li?

Tags: 8, theming, navigation

I want to generate the html elements and their classes to fit my styling of the main menu.

I'm confused by all the near-possibilities offered in the api documentation and by looking at core themes etc. and still can't quite see what I have to do, or where I have to do it.
I would be very grateful for clear pointers to:

1. which php functions I have to write;
2. which variables I need to add / update;
3. in which files the functions will go.

Presumably, in `MYTHEME.theme` I will need a preprocess function of some sort to add to the `attributes` and `item.attributes` variables that `links.html.twig` uses to print the menu `ul` and the menu item `li`'s.

[Update]
So far I have discovered one way to place classes on the Main Menu's `ul` but ideally I would like to add a class to each submenu's `ul` indicating the depth of the sub-menu.
And I cannot locate any documentation or examples from which I can understand the generation / modifying of the main menu's individual `li`nk items.

This function goes into the file  `MYTHEME.theme`.

```php
function MYTHEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {

  // Pass the main menu and secondary menu to the template as render arrays.
  if (!empty($variables['main_menu'])) {
    $variables['main_menu']['#attributes']['id'] = 'main-menu-links';
    $variables['main_menu']['#attributes']['class'] = array('links', 'clearfix', 'MYNEW_class');
  }

}
```

Comment: You possibly want to wait for https://www.drupal.org/node/2256521 to land, that's a huge refactoring of the whole menu link system and it's likely that it will affect whatever you're currently doing.

Comment: Thanks @Bedir. It looks like a mighty meaty refactoring! I'll keep the question open and aim to answer it when the new code hits an available alpha and I've had a chance to look at it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Override the twig file for the main menu by saving *menu--main.html.twig* in your theme. Copy the original *menu.html.twig* from *core/modules/system/templates/menu.html.twig*, or *core/themes/classy/templates/navigation/menu.html.twig* if your theme extends Classy.

You can then modify the [macro](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/tags/macro.html) used to generate the menu output. To get a class on the `<ul>`'s to indicate level, you could do this.

```
{% if menu_level == 0 %}
  <ul{{ attributes.addClass('menu', 'menu-level--' ~ menu_level) }}>
{% else %}
  <ul class="menu {{ 'menu-level--' ~ menu_level }}">
{% endif %}
```

You could do similar manipulations to the `<li>`'s.

```
<li{{ item.attributes }}>
```

Use `.addClass('class-name')` to add more CSS classes.

```
<li{{ item.attributes.addClass('class-name') }}>
```

If you're a HTML/class name snob like myself you can also remove classes.

```
{{ item.attributes.removeClass('menu-item') }}
```

Comment: Nice answer @wesruv, I made some edits (pending) to try to answer the OP more directly on adding a class to indicate depth. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks Cottser, I feel like I barely deserve credit for the much improved answer :)

Answer (score 2):

The way to get the main menu with items in all levels has been resolved in [Drupal 8 - "Implement menu links as plugins", trying to build a menu tree](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/126477/drupal-8-implement-menu-links-as-plugins-trying-to-build-a-menu-tree/126483#126483)

To add class to ul and li, we got 3 options:

A. Override menuTree service:

1. create new MenulinkTree in your module MyprojectMenuLinkTree that extends core's MenuLinkTree
2. Override MenulinkTree::build by adding MyprojectMenuLinkTree::build
3. Update your level specifi class in logic like this https://gist.github.com/vijaycs85/308d2d0287a9ab1cd168
4. ovrride defult menu.link_tree at sites/default/services.yml https://gist.github.com/vijaycs85/1179c6009c6932405f10

P.S: Not very sure, if you need to do these whole override for adding class.

B. Override just tree build on theme layer:

1. Add the code in mytheme.theme file: https://gist.github.com/vijaycs85/61f2b2757f83aaa5260e

C. Using Drupal.behaviors.MYTHEME in JavaScript (from https://www.drupal.org/project/gratis)

1. Create MYTHEME/script.js
2. Add MYTHEME.behaviour.menuTree
3. Update this code: https://gist.github.com/vijaycs85/346c14aedffcafe8945e

Comment: Thanks @vijaycs85. Since my question is essentially about theming, I think either of your options B and C will be sufficient for what I want. We temporarily abandoned our D8 project and until we eventually get back to it, it looks like you have provided the answer.

Comment: (I took this opportunity to re-read all 155 posts in https://www.drupal.org/node/2256521 to regain some confidence in continuing to invest in D8!)

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal8 - if you want to use **Macros** & add levels etc to the menu, you need to pass the variables that you need to extend/include accordingly:

Base Template Screen Shot: [image]

Base Template Code:

```
{% import _self as menus %}

{{ menus.menu_links(items, attributes, 0, list_add_class, item_add_class) }}

{% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level, list_add_class, item_add_class) %}
  {% import _self as menus %}
  {% if items %}
    {% if menu_level == 0 %}
      <ul{{ attributes.addClass(list_add_class) }}>
    {% else %}
      <ul>
    {% endif %}
    {% for item in items %}
      <li{{ item.attributes.addClass(item_add_class) }}>
        {{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
        {% if item.below %}
          {{ menus.menu_links(item.below, attributes, menu_level + 1, list_add_class, item_add_class) }}
        {% endif %}
      </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

Child template code:

```
{% include "@drupalastic/navigation/menu_base.html.twig" with {
    item_add_class: ['my-custom-item-class', 'my-another-custom-item-class'],
    list_add_class: ['my-custom-list-class']
  }
%}
```

End Result:
[image]