# Assign unique IDs to HTML elements via twig file

Tags: theming

I have a "block--system-menu-block.html.twig" file, which prints the menu content into the menu.

```
{# Menu. #}
{% block content %}
  {{ content }}
{% endblock %}
```

However, I would like each menu item (the resulting `<li>` elements) to get a unique ID.
For example:

```
<li id="list-item-1">abc</li>
<li id="list-item-2">abc</li>
```

...

The idea is that I can use that in my css to have different colors or hover colors for my menu items.
I have already achieved this with JavaScript on the front end, but I would rather have it done in the backend, in the twig files.
Is that possible?
If so, any ideas?

Comment: Is the a reason you need ids? Can you just use the :nth-child selector?

Comment: This post help? https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/162705/8667

Comment: I can also use classes, does not have to be IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Copy `/core/themes/bartik/templates/classy/navigation/menu.html.twig`

and modify a bit:

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Theme override to display a menu.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - menu_name: The machine name of the menu.
 * - items: A nested list of menu items. Each menu item contains:
 *   - attributes: HTML attributes for the menu item.
 *   - below: The menu item child items.
 *   - title: The menu link title.
 *   - url: The menu link url, instance of \Drupal\Core\Url
 *   - localized_options: Menu link localized options.
 *   - is_expanded: TRUE if the link has visible children within the current
 *     menu tree.
 *   - is_collapsed: TRUE if the link has children within the current menu tree
 *     that are not currently visible.
 *   - in_active_trail: TRUE if the link is in the active trail.
 */
#}
{% import _self as menus %}

{#
  We call a macro which calls itself to render the full tree.
  @see https://twig.symfony.com/doc/1.x/tags/macro.html
#}
{{ menus.menu_links(items, attributes, 0) }}

{% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level) %}
  {% import _self as menus %}
  {% if items %}
    {% if menu_level == 0 %}
      <ul{{ attributes.addClass('menu') }}>
    {% else %}
      <ul class="menu">
    {% endif %}
    {% set count = 1 %} {# <------------------ Added #}
    {% for item in items %}
      {%
        set classes = [
          'menu-item-' ~ count, {# <------------------ Modified #}
          item.is_expanded ? 'menu-item--expanded',
          item.is_collapsed ? 'menu-item--collapsed',
          item.in_active_trail ? 'menu-item--active-trail',
        ]
      %}
      <li{{ item.attributes.addClass(classes) }}>
        {{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
        {% if item.below %}
          {{ menus.menu_links(item.below, attributes, menu_level + 1) }}
        {% endif %}
      </li>
      {% set count = count + 1 %} {# <------------------ Added #}
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```

## Result

[image]

Then you can do, Ex: `#menu-block-id .menu-item-1 { border: solid green; }`

Answer (score 0):

I used a variation of @no-sssweat 's answer.

```
{#
/**
 * @file
 * Theme override to display a menu.
 *
 * Available variables:
 * - menu_name: The machine name of the menu.
 * - items: A nested list of menu items. Each menu item contains:
 *   - attributes: HTML attributes for the menu item.
 *   - below: The menu item child items.
 *   - title: The menu link title.
 *   - url: The menu link url, instance of \Drupal\Core\Url
 *   - localized_options: Menu link localized options.
 *   - is_expanded: TRUE if the link has visible children within the current
 *     menu tree.
 *   - is_collapsed: TRUE if the link has children within the current menu tree
 *     that are not currently visible.
 *   - in_active_trail: TRUE if the link is in the active trail.
 */
#}
{% import _self as menus %}

{#
  We call a macro which calls itself to render the full tree.
  @see https://twig.symfony.com/doc/1.x/tags/macro.html
#}
{{ menus.menu_links(items, attributes, 0) }}

{% macro menu_links(items, attributes, menu_level) %}
  {% import _self as menus %}
  {% if items %}
    {% if menu_level == 0 %}
      <ul{{ attributes.addClass('menu') }}>
    {% else %}
      <ul class="menu">
    {% endif %}
    {% set count = 1 %} {# <------------------ Added #}
    {% for item in items %}
      <li{{ item.attributes }} class="menu-item-{{ count }}"> {# <------------------ This is more simple than @no-sssweat s answer #}
        {{ link(item.title, item.url) }}
        {% if item.below %}
          {{ menus.menu_links(item.below, attributes, menu_level + 1) }}
        {% endif %}
      </li>
      {% set count = count + 1 %} {# <------------------ Added #}
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
  {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
```